How to add nonce to react-compiler injected script?
I started using React Compiler.
I have noticed that it injects code like this:
<script>
  $RC("B:1", "S:1")
</script>

You can see an example of this if you view the source of https://pillser.com/minerals
The problem is that I also want to use Content-Security-Policy:
const createCspHeaderValue = (nonce: string) => {
  return [
    `default-src 'self'`,
    `script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-${nonce}'`,
    // `style-src 'nonce-${nonce}' 'self' 'unsafe-inline'`,
    // `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'`,
    `style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'`,
    `img-src 'self' data:`,
    `font-src 'self'`,
    `connect-src 'self'`,
    `frame-src 'self'`,
    // TODO find a way to restrict form to pillser.com
    // This was causing problems when clicking on product links
    // `form-action 'self'`,
    `base-uri 'self'`,
    `object-src 'none'`,
    `frame-ancestors 'self'`,
    `media-src 'self'`,
  ].join('; ');
};

If I enable the script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-${nonce}' header, then all the React Compiler injected scripts break.
Using unsafe-inline fixes the issue, but it prevents me from using safe policies.

Turns out React renderToPipeableStream accepts nonce property.
https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToPipeableStream#reference
Passing nonce to renderToPipeableStream as an option made the scripts render with nonce= attribute, e.g.
<script nonce="359b6e2535e850aefedb63f553682e15">$RC("B:1","S:1")</script>

